# Android - multiple AAR variant Nexus upload

Tags: android, gradle, module, android-gradle-plugin, nexus

I have a project with a structure like below. It has a '`main-module`' that is the focus of our development, which should be able to publish AARs for two variants (debug, release) to Nexus. We also have a bunch of other dependency modules and a test app.

`project
   |
   |- app
   |- main-module
   |- module-a
   |- module-b
   ...`

I'm looking to run a build that will package the `main-module` AARs an then upload both of these to Nexus repos. The debug AAR will go to a snapshots repo, and the release version will go to a release repo. I have some puzzle pieces but I'm not quite sure how to tie it together.

What I have:

**Build AARs**

`gradlew assemble`

**Publish an AAR**

```
project.uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: "deployment", password: "password123")
        }
        pom.version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
        pom.artifactId = "MainModule"
        pom.groupId = "com.myorg.test"
    }
}
```

The build works and I can push a version to Nexus. I don't know how to provide config for the debug and release versions so they have the correct repository (e.g. `/snapshots` vs `/release`) and the correct version (release version name won't contain `SNAPSHOT`).

Once working I'll move the names, versions and credentials out to properties, with the credentials not checked in to source control before someone points that out.

Using:

- gradle-wrapper 4.4
- gradle plugin 3.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several days of digging around I found the solution. This is pretty rough, I haven't optimised it yet, but the solution works. Note it assumes your aar files contain the text 'debug' and 'release' in the name, if they don't then you can adjust to your project. I wouldn't know how this applies to modules that have more than just the debug and release variants, or if product flavours are involved.

**android-maven-gradle-plugin**

Integrate the [android-maven-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin). Steps are in the documentation link.

**Module build.gradle**

`apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'`

```
afterEvaluate {
  uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {

            addFilter('debug') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.name.contains("debug")
            }
            addFilter('release') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.name.contains("release")
            }

            pom('debug').groupId = 'com.yourgroup'
            pom('release').groupId = 'com.yourgroup'
            pom('debug').artifactId = "MyArtifact"
            pom('release').artifactId = "MyArtifact"
            pom('debug').version = android.defaultConfig.versionName + "-SNAPSHOT"
            pom('release').version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
            pom.packaging = 'aar'

            repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/") {
                authentication(userName: 'user'), password: 'pwd')
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
                authentication(userName: 'user'), password: 'pwd')
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```